# Непонятно куда пропадают cookie

Tags: javascript, flask

Возможно это очень глупый вопрос, но сколько не гуглил, ничего не могу найти.
Есть сайт на фласке с рабочей авторизацией, в devtools в хроме точно видно, что куки от сайта приходят и при подключении к сайту они (при наличии) отправляются, в куках хранится session_id, но если попытаться получить к ним доступ из консоли хрома (через document.cookie, где они по идее и должны быть(наверное)) или через подключенный js файл, выясняется, что эта строка с куками пустая, как к ним тогда получить доступ? этот session_id же должен где-то храниться.. localStorage и sessionStorage тоже пустой.

Comment: Читаем про http-only куки

Comment: oh, почему-то это пропустил, спасибо.